# Requiring an SOContact field when contact is not being overridden

Tags: acumatica

On the Sales Order screen Financial Settings tab, I need to make the Bill-To Contact Email field required. The email field needs to be required regardless of whether or not "Override Contact" is checked.

Typically you can make a field required by just setting `PXDefault("", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)`. However, that is only working if "Override Contact" is checked.

If the contact is not overridden, then the email field is disabled, and it is ignoring the persisting check and not requiring the email field.

**How can I require the email field even when the billing contact is not being overridden?**

Here's my code right now. Again, this is working if the contact is overridden but has no effect when the contact is not overridden.

```
 public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry.CarrierRates, SOOrderEntry>
    {
        // Make Financial Settings Email required
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
        [PXDefault("", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
        public void SOBillingContact_Email_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
    }
```

### Another Approach

I've also tried using an event handler to raise an exception. This approach is also not working.

```
public virtual void SOBillingContact_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    SOBillingContact contact = (SOBillingContact)e.Row;
    if (contact != null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Email))
        {
            cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOBillingContact.email>(e.Row, ((SOBillingContact)e.Row).Email, 
                new PXSetPropertyException("Email is required", PXErrorLevel.Error));
        }
    }
}
```

This code is running but the exception appears to get suppressed and is never displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

First, I did make the `SOBillingContact.Email` field required on the screen using Automation steps

[image]

But as explained in the original question, this only is effective when the billing contact is being overridden.

To get the field to be required when the billing contact is NOT being overridden (i.e. Override Contact = False), I added an event handler for SOOrder_RowPersisting. In the event handler, I both throw a row persisting exception and also raise exception handling on the billing contact email field.

Throwing the row persisting exception stops the record from being saved (which is what I want) and displays an error, but it also keeps the changes in the cache so that the user can just correct the error and save again without losing their changes. Raising the field exception attaches an exception to the field itself so that it's clear to the user what they need to fix. If you just raise the field exception without throwing a row persisting exception, it gets suppressed by subsequent events and never gets displayed.

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    protected virtual void SOOrder_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
        SOOrder order = (SOOrder)e.Row;
        if (order == null) { return; }

        if (e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert || e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Update)
        {
            SOBillingContact billingContact = PXSelect<SOBillingContact,
                    Where<SOBillingContact.contactID, Equal<Required<SOOrder.billContactID>>>>.Select(Base, order.BillContactID);
            PXCache billingContactCache = this.Base.Caches[typeof(SOBillingContact)];

            if (billingContact.Email == null || billingContact.Email == "")
            {
                billingContactCache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOBillingContact.email>(billingContact, billingContactCache.GetValueExt<SOBillingContact.email>(billingContact),
                  new PXSetPropertyException("Financial Email is required", PXErrorLevel.RowError));

                throw new PXRowPersistingException(typeof(SOBillingContact.email).Name, null, "Financial email is required");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PXUIRequiredAttribute?  It allows you to conditionally determine when the field is required.  Otherwise, remove the PersistingCheck or add Required = true to the PXUIField attribute as well.

Example of PXUIRequiredAttribute:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXDefault]
[PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Current<SOBillingContact.overrideContact>, Equal<True>>))]
public void SOBillingContact_Email_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

Untested in your application, but this follows the format of what I use in my code.

Also, if you make it required, remember to open the field to enable entry so that you don't cause validation to prevent saving for a record that the user cannot make right.  That "unlocking the field" could be required via either Automation Steps or UI Workflow or maybe in the RowSelected event.

Comment: Hi @Brian, I actually want the field to be required at all times, not conditionally. The problem is that if the contact is not overridden, then all the fields for the contact, including email, are disabled and the required attribute doesn't take effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just added another approach that I've tried to the original post. This second approach uses event handlers but it's also not working.